# Adding a Row Number to a Temp Table in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I need to get one column from one table and put it in a temp table but also add another column to the temp table that would be the row number but I am not sure how to do that.

The basic problem I have is I have a table of communities and a table of sales and I need to go through the sales table and count how many were in each community. Then if a community has more than 5 then to increment a variable that signifies how many models made quota. My thought was to have a temp table that has each community in it alone with a row number and loop through that based on that row number through the sales table to make sure that I check each sale with each community.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: // how many models made quota// What is a "model" ? How does it relate to community and sales ?      Your approach sound very procedural and rbar (row by row)...... perhaps there is a better way.  Code up some tables (using the #temp example below in my response ) , put some fake data in it, and then the desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use IDENTITY on a #temp table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end


CREATE TABLE #TableOne
( 
SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1) , 
NameOf varchar(12)
)


Insert into #TableOne (NameOf)

Select Alpha From 
(
    Select 'A' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'Y' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'B' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'Z' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'C' as Alpha
) as derived1
Order by Alpha


select * from #TableOne




IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end
```

Output:

```
SurrogateKeyIDENTITY    NameOf
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   Y
5   Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
CREATE TABLE #TableOne
( 
SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int IDENTITY (1,1) , 
NameOf varchar(12)
)
```